# Simple Stack, how to initialize Node at 0 instead of null

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to implement a very simple stack, however, it seems that I need to use a node for this. I have the below which compiles and works fine, however, it throws a lot of errors until someone makes the first push. I am in a situation where I cannot control what is in the consumer's main method, so I think it would be best to avoid these errors and just initialize a new stack object with an initial value of zero. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out just how to do that. Would anyone here be able to advise me?

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackQ {
    Node top;

public StackQ() {
    top=null;
}

class Node {
    public int x = 0;
    public Node next;
    Node(int d) {x=d; next=null;}
    public int getData() {return x;}
}

public int pop() {
    if(top!=null) {
        int item = top.x;
        top = top.next;
        return item;
        }
    return -1;
}

public void push(int x) {
    Node t = new Node(x);
    t.next = this.top;
    this.top = t;
}

public int top() {
    if (top == null) throw new EmptyStackException();
    return top.x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackQ mainStack = new StackQ();
}

}
```

Comment: `a lot of errors` what errors?

Comment: "however, it throws a lot of errors until someone makes the first push" - If you try to pop (or top) the stack when nothing's been pushed, it SHOULD throw an exception.  If that's not the problem, can you be more specific?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the EmptyStackException when you call `top()` is my main concern. But perhaps this is how it's supposed to work, OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're using `top()` without putting anything in the stack, they are using your stack wrong.  Seriously, they *should* be getting an exception.  It's up to them to not use your stack that way, and it's up to them to properly handle that exception.

But if you *really* wanted to always start your stack with a 0 in it (which, to be perfectly clear, I am advising against doing) just put that in your constructor.

```
public StackQ() {
    top=new Node(0);
}
```

Comment: I agree completely, BUT it would probably be a good idea to provide a method allowing the caller to *know* if it can call top() safely, like size() or isEmpty() (or both). It would also be a good idea to be consistent: pop() should also throw an EmptyStackException instead of returning a valid int value when the stack is empty: the caller, when getting -1 from pop(), can't know if -1 was really on the stack, or if it was empty.

Comment: I agree with all of that.